# Заливка Java Web project на VPS

Tags: java, веб-программирование, intellij-idea, war

Как задеплоить проект в war пакете на удаленный сервер? Например через intellij idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все проще, чем я думал. Просто установил на сервере томкат, jre и mysql. Затем закинул war в папку tomcat/webapps/ и изменил порт 8080 на 80 и локалхост на домен моего сайта.